# ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm, clean-architecture

Stack => Nodejs, Express.js, Typeorm

I'm trying to use typeorm with typescript. I have created a repository to save the survivor information. But I keep getting this error:

```sh
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
    at new ConnectionNotFoundError (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
    at ConnectionManager.get (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
    at Object.getRepository (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/index.ts:284:35)
    at new CreateSurvivorRepository (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/repositories/typeorm/CreateSurvivorRepository.ts:10:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/useCases/CreateSurvivor/index.ts:6:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:547:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/private/var/folders/fr/6x3p83cj6r73h57k1_x6nctc0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-7748782675459163.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/private/var/folders/fr/6x3p83cj6r73h57k1_x6nctc0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-7748782675459163.js:114:20)
[ERROR] 00:28:59 ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
```

My ormconfig.json is this one:

```json
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "teste",
  "database": "codeminer_backend",
  "entities": [
     "src/database/models/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
     "src/database/migrations/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
  }
}
```

Those are the code that the error appoint:

`at new CreateSurvivorRepository (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/repositories/typeorm/CreateSurvivorRepository.ts:10:26)`

```js
import { getRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { SurvivorOrm } from '../../database/models/SurvivorsOrm'
import { ICreateSurvivorRequestDTO } from '../../useCases/CreateSurvivor/CreateSurvivorDTO'
import { ICreateSurvivorRepository } from '../ICreateSurvivorRepository'

export class CreateSurvivorRepository implements ICreateSurvivorRepository {
  private ormRepository: Repository<SurvivorOrm>

  constructor () {
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(SurvivorOrm)
  }

  public async create ({ id, name, age, gender, lastLocation, infected }: ICreateSurvivorRequestDTO): Promise<SurvivorOrm> {
    const survivor = await this.ormRepository.create({ id, name, age, gender, lastLocation, infected })

    await this.ormRepository.save(survivor)

    return survivor
  }
}
```

`at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Wblech/codeminerTeste/backend/src/useCases/CreateSurvivor/index.ts:6:41)`

```js
import { CreateInventoryRepository } from '../../repositories/typeorm/CreateInventoryRepository'
import { CreateSurvivorRepository } from '../../repositories/typeorm/CreateSurvivorRepository'
import { CreateSurvivorController } from './CreateSurvivorController'
import { CreateSurvivorUseCase } from './CreateSurvivorUseCase'

const createSurvivorRepositoryTypeOrm = new CreateSurvivorRepository()
const createInventoryRepositoryTypeOrm = new CreateInventoryRepository()

const createSurvivorUseCase = new CreateSurvivorUseCase(
  createSurvivorRepositoryTypeOrm,
  createInventoryRepositoryTypeOrm
)

const createSurvivorController = new CreateSurvivorController(
  createSurvivorUseCase
)

export { createSurvivorUseCase, createSurvivorController }
```

My connection is in a file in the path './src/database/index.ts' and is this one:

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm'

createConnection()
```

And I import the connection in this file called server.ts:

```js
import express from 'express'
import { router } from './router'
import './database'

const port = 8081

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(router)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running at ${port}`))
```

I'm really stuck at this

Answer (score 1):

Basically - TypeORM tries to get the *"default"* connection option, but If not found then throws an error:

> ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

We can solve this issue by doing some kind of **sanity check** before establishing a connection - luckily we have `.has()` method on `getConnectionManager()`.

```js
import { Connection, getConnectionManager, getConnectionOptions, 
  createConnection, getConnection, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
    
    async init() {
    let connection: Connection;
    let queryRunner: QueryRunner;

     if (!getConnectionManager().has('default')) {
        const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions();
        connection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);
      } else {
        connection = getConnection();
      }

    queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner(); 
 }
```